# What's the difference between exists and defined?

Tags: perl

What is the difference between

```
if (defined $hash{$key}) { }
```

and

```
if (exists $hash{$key}) { }
```

When do I know which to use?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

This is well-documented in the perldoc entries for [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) and [`exists`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html). Here's a quick summary:

`defined $hash{key}` tells you whether or not the value for the given key is defined (i.e. not `undef`). Use it to distinguish between undefined values and values that are false in a boolean context such as `0` and `''`.

`exists $hash{key}` tells you whether or not `%hash` contains the given key. Use it to distinguish between undefined values and non-existent ones.

This is easiest to see with an example. Given this hash:

```
my %hash = (a => 1, b => 0, c => undef);
```

Here are the results for retrieval, defined-ness, and existence:

```
# key  value  defined  exists
a          1        1       1
b          0        1       1
c      undef        0       1
d      undef        0       0
```

In practice, people often write just `if ($hash{key}) {...}` because (in many common cases) only true values are meaningful/possible. If false values are valid you *must* add `defined()` to the test. `exists()` is used much less often. The most common case is probably when using a hash as a set. e.g.

```
my %set = map { $_ => undef } 'a' .. 'z';
```

Using `undef` for set values has a few advantages:

1. It more accurately represents the intent (only the keys are meaningful, not the values).
2. All `undef` values share a single allocation (which saves memory).
3. `exists()` tests are slightly faster (because Perl doesn't have to retrieve the value, only determine that there is one).

It also has the disadvantage that you have to use `exists()` to check for set membership, which requires more typing and will do the wrong thing if you forget it.

Another place where `exists` is useful is to probe locked hashes before attempting to retrieve a value (which would trigger an exception).

Comment: Very nicely explained.

Comment: Also, `defined` can also be used on other kinds of variables, while `exists` will throw an error if not used on a hash or array key (or a subroutine).

Answer (score 15):

`defined` checks the value of the variable, `exists` checks if it has been previously declared/initialized. If it exists, plain and simple.

E.g.:

```
$hash{$key} = undef;
# various return values:
exists  $hash{$key};  # true
defined $hash{$key};  # false
$hash{$key};          # false

$hash{$key} = 0;
# various return values:
exists  $hash{$key};  # true
defined $hash{$key};  # true
$hash{$key};          # false
exists $hash{$foo};   # false
```

Comment: And `defined $hash{$foo}; #false` I suppose?

Comment: @Sandra Yes, uninitialized values are always undefined. Think of it as the difference between declaration and initialization: `my $var` exists, and contains the value `undef`. `my $var = 0` exists, and contains the value 0, therefore defined.

Comment: `$hash{$key}` returns the value for `$key`. While this can be interpreted as a Boolean, it isn't one. Your first example should return `undef`, the second one `0`.

Comment: @Michael True, but this was in the context of if-statements (see question).

Comment: but beware. Using something like `if( defined $hash{$key} ) ...` may add the key (with undef as value) if the key does not exists. Thats why i always use `if( exists $hash{$key} && defined $hash{$key})`.

Comment: @some_coder No, that is incorrect. You are thinking of [autovivification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification), and that occurs in Perl when you refer to a multi-dimensional structure: You create the level below to check the level above. E.g. `if (defined $hash{a}{b})` will create `$hash{a}` if it does not already exist. But it will never create `$hash{a}{b}`.

Answer (score 7):

Perl [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html):

> When used on a hash element, **defined** tells
>   you whether the value is defined, not
>   whether the key exists in the hash.
>   Use **exists** for the latter purpose.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the [perldoc on `exists`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html):

> Given an expression that specifies an element of a hash, returns true if the specified element in the hash has ever been initialized, even if the corresponding value is undefined.
>
> A hash or array element can be true only if it's defined and defined only if it exists, but the reverse doesn't necessarily hold true.

That is, a hash can contain an undefined element, and if that is the case, the `defined`-check will return `false`, whereas the `exists`-check will return `true`.

Therefore, you should use `exists` if you wish to know if a given entry exists in the hash, and `defined` if you wish to know if the given entry exists and is defined.

Comment: Yes. `exists` checks if the hash contains the given key, but not what the value of it is, while `defined` looks at value at the given key and sees if it is defined or not (and if the key doesn't exist, it gets back an `undef`, so it works even if the key's not there.)

Answer (score 3):

This example shows the difference. In general defined works for any structure and exist is related to hashes.

```
my %hash=("1"=>undef);
print "exists:".exists($hash{"1"})."\n";
print "defined:".defined($hash{"1"})."\n";
```

The difference is small and not so obvious, so expect that people will mess with it.