# compare one hash key with other hash's value

Tags: perl, hash

How do you compare one hash's key with other hash's value? Here is the output of my hashes. I only need to return boolean output.

( My code is kind of mess right now, so please forgive me for not posting here. I just need the logic, I will try to work further to incorporate it.)

```
    $VAR1 = {
      '5555' => [
                    '13570'
                  ]
    };
    $VAR1 = {
      '13570' => [
                   '[04/Jun/2013:15:06:13'
                 ]
            };
```

Thanks.

Comment: [And what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: `defined $VAR1->{$VAR1->{'5555'}}` should tell you if a key matching the value of $VAR1's key '5555' exists in $VAR1 .... for varying definitions of VAR1.....  8/

Comment: I tried , | if (defined $hash1{$key2}) | , here key2 refers from the second hash.

Answer (score 1):

`$VAR1` is assigned twice. I guess this is a typo. Do you actually want to check whether a hash contains a given key, although this key is the same (`eq`) with a value in another hash?

You can use `exists`, e.g., `if (exists $hash{$key}) {...}`. For the difference between `defined` and `exists`, see [What's the difference between exists and defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534573/whats-the-difference-between-exists-and-defined)

BTW, as you declare anonymous hash with `{ }` and anonymous array with `[ ]`, the de-reference is needed before getting the actual content; otherwise you just use the references (like a pointer in c language).

Comment: No, it's not a typo, it's a result of using Data::Dumper to display the hashes. Data::Dumper doesn't have access to the actual names of the variables, so it calls them all `$VAR1`.

Answer (score 0):

What's throwing you off here is that your hash values aren't the actual *values*, but rather array references (as shown by the `[ ... ]` in your Data::Dumper output) pointing to single-element arrays which contain the actual data.  So you need to dereference them and grab the first element from the resulting array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %hash1 = ('5555' => [ '13570' ]);
my %hash2 = ('13570' => [ '[04/Jun/2013:15:06:13' ]);

for (keys %hash1) {
  my $first_key = $_;
  my $second_key = $hash1{$first_key}[0];
  say "$first_key -> $second_key -> $hash2{$second_key}[0]";
}
```

Output:

```
5555 -> 13570 -> [04/Jun/2013:15:06:13
```

**Edit:**  Alternate code to check all values in each `%hash1` entry and display all corresponding values for each in `%hash2`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %hash1 = ('5555' => [ '13570', '8675309' ]);
my %hash2 = (
  '13570' => [ '[04/Jun/2013:15:06:13' ],
  8675309 => [ 'Jenny', 'I got your number' ],
);


for (keys %hash1) {
  my $first_key = $_;
  for my $second_key ( @{$hash1{$first_key}} ) {
    if (exists $hash2{$second_key}) {
      say "$first_key -> $second_key ->";
      say "\t$_" for @{$hash2{$second_key}};
    }
  } 
}
```

Output:

```
5555 -> 13570 ->
    [04/Jun/2013:15:06:13
5555 -> 8675309 ->
    Jenny
    I got your number
```

Comment: Thanks Dave for the response, this is what I was looking for, however as you understand that first hash might contain multiple values, hence need to grep for existence.

Comment: @JohnRein See the alternate version I edited in for handling multiple values in the arrays.

Comment: Wow, this is great.Please ignore the second key in hash 2, as it is not common between the two hash. We just need firstkey to compare the value of hash1.

Comment: Why don't you just write it `for my $first_key (...){...}`?

Answer (score -3):

I'm getting this as how to compare a non encrypted value to an encrypted value. I could be wrong though.

If this is the case...

```
if HASH_VALUE(nonEncrypted) is equal to encryptedValue
    do something
else
    do something else
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate further?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question

Comment: This question is about "hash" the Perl data type (called a "hash table", "associative array", or "dictionary" in other languages), not cryptographic hashes.

Comment: The question is about a Perl data structure. This answer is about a one way hash function. Please delete it.