# Are the following snippets equivalent?

Tags: perl, scripting

Are the following two snippets functionally equivalent? When I do it the first way, I get a bunch of `use of uninitialized value` warnings because I try to evaluate the nonexistent `$seen{$key}`. Hoping to avoid this. `$seen{$key}` is always either 1 or undefined, it never takes on any other value throughout the script.

```
if($seen{$key}=='1'){

    print "key already seen\n";

}else{

    print "key not seen\n";
    #do stuff with key
    $seen{$key}='1';

}
```

~~~~

```
if(!$seen{$key}){
   print "key not seen\n";
   #do stuff with key
   $seen{$key}='1';
}else{

   print "key already seen\n";
}
```

Comment: `$seen{$key} != 1` instead of `!$seen{$key}` would be true equivalent, but in your case it doesn't matter.

Comment: If `$seen{key}` does not exist, would `$seen{$key} != 1` give an error?

Comment: It would give warning under `warnings`.

Comment: Is it bad form for a Perl script to give warnings?

Comment: Warnings demand your attention, to improve the code.

Comment: `print $seen{$key}++ ? "key already seen" : "key not seen", "\n";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the documentation of ["Truth and Falsehood"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood).

Basically "0", an empty string "" or undef is false. If you try to use a undef value in numerical context you will receive an error "Use of uninitialized value $variable in numeric ..."

Answer (score 0):

consider this:

```
#at start of script ----------
use warnings;
use strict;
# ----------------------------

if(exists $seen{$key}){

    print "key already seen\n";

}else{

    print "key not seen\n";
    #do stuff with key
    $seen{$key}='1';

}
```

Besides the issue of 'what is truth' (a truly layered question, not suitable for SO) you seem to not know the 'exist' function ..

you can get some background in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534573/whats-the-difference-between-exists-and-defined) Stack Ooverflow 'Question/Answer' that discusses *whats-the-difference-between-exists-and-defined*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My script runs on data that's highly heterogeneous, and therefore often a variable will be undefined for one instance and defined for the next. For example, to generate variables, it could split one line of a csv file that looks like `a,b,c,d,e` and the next looks like `,,,a,`.  I do quite a bit of calculation/comparisons with these variables. Do I need to check whether a variable exists before everything I do to them? That would require many more lines of code...( but I also don't want my script to generate hundreds of warnings)

Comment: Since you're not accessing distinct variables with different names, but rather hash-table entries, you should be able to write a generic accessor function that does the checking, then call that.