# Defined vs. exists with Raku hash keys

Tags: raku

I am learning Raku from Perl.

I am looking at the adverb `:exists` https://docs.raku.org/type/Hash#:exists but there isn't a `:defined` adverb

but I am concerned because there is a distinction between perl's `exists` & `defined`: [What's the difference between exists and defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534573/whats-the-difference-between-exists-and-defined)

How can I do something like this in Raku?

```
if (defined $hash{key}) {
   $hash{key}++;
} else {
   $hash{key} = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if defined %hash{'key'} {
   %hash{'key'}++;
} else {
   %hash{'key'} = 1;
}
```

Use the `defined` routine or method. See [5to6-perlfunc -- defined](https://docs.raku.org/language/5to6-perlfunc#defined)

Answer (score 7):

`defined` is a property of a value.

`exists` is a variation selector of the hash indexing operation.

This is true in both Perl5 and Perl6.
It's just that they way they handle it is different.

---

Say you have a hash like this:

```perl6
my %h = ( a => 1, b => 2, c => Int );
```

It has three keys:

```perl6
say %h.keys; # (a b c)
```

You can get the value associated with a key:

```perl6
my $value = %h{'a'};
```

You can ask the value if it was `defined`

```perl6
say defined $value; # True
```

Now let's try it with `c`:

```perl6
my $value = %h{'c'};
say defined $value; # False
```

And with `D`:

```perl6
my $value = %h{'D'};
say defined $value; # False
```

Note that even though `D` isn't a key in the hash, the value you get back looks the same as as looking up `c`.

The value doesn't know how you got ahold of it. It has no clue about the hash indexing operation.
It is the same even if you don't store it in a variable.

```perl6
say defined %h{'c'}; # False
say defined %h{'D'}; # False
```

So we have to tell the indexing operation instead to give us that information.

```perl6
my $exists = %h{'D'}:exists;
say $exists; # False
```

Also if you use the result of `%h{'D'}` as a container, it [magically] starts to exist.

```perl6
say %h{'D'}:exists; # False

say %h{'D'}.perl;   # Any
say %h{'D'}:exists; # False

%h{'D'}++;
say %h{'D'}:exists; # True

say %h{'D'}; # 1
```

---

So then why is it different than Perl5?

In Perl5 `exists` and `defined` are keywords. In Perl6 they are not.
They are not special in any way, shape, or form in Perl6.

Here is the Perl5 version for checking `exists`:

```perl
use v5.12.0;
use warnings;

my %h = ( a => 1, b => 2, c => undef );

my $exists = exists $h{D};
say $exists ? 'True' : 'False'; # False
```

If you call the compiler with `-MO=Concise` you will get a listing of the opcodes that it would execute.

Here is just the part that shows that `exists` is an opcode:

```
…
d     <;> nextstate(main 5 -e:1) v:%,us,*,&,{,$,fea=2 ->e

g     <2> sassign vKS/2 ->h                          # <----- =

-        <1> ex-exists sK/1 ->f                      # <-\
e           <+> multideref($h{"D"}) sK/EXISTS ->f    # <--+-- exists $h{D}
-              <0> ex-padhv sR ->e                   # <-/

f        <0> padsv[$exists:5,6] sRM*/LVINTRO ->g     # <----- $exists

h     <;> nextstate(main 6 -e:1) v:%,us,*,&,{,$,fea=2 ->i
…
```

The `multideref($h{"D"})` is marked with `EXISTS`, and there is `ex-exists` opcode.

The listing for `defined` is very similar.

---

One of the design goals of Perl6 was to have as few special cases as possible.
This is why neither `exists` or `defined` are keywords.

If you look for where [`defined`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/e50f4f2e335a444d8ef2cb4d8c53bb4f63134fda/src/core/Mu.pm6#L939-L940) is in the Rakudo codebase you find this:

```perl6
proto sub defined(Mu, *%) is pure {*}
multi sub defined(Mu \x) { x.defined }
```

`defined` is just a subroutine that takes one value, and calls the `.defined` method on that value.

Since it does a method call, the value gets a say on whether it is considered to be defined or not.

The default that all values inherit is in [Mu.defined source](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/e50f4f2e335a444d8ef2cb4d8c53bb4f63134fda/src/core/Mu.pm6#L108-L110):

```perl6
proto method defined(|) {*}
multi method defined(Mu:U: --> False) { }
multi method defined(Mu:D: --> True)  { }
```

So the default is for the type object to be undefined, and an instance to be defined.

One notable exception is the [Failure](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/e50f4f2e335a444d8ef2cb4d8c53bb4f63134fda/src/core/Failure.pm6#L52) object:

```perl6
multi method defined(Failure:D: --> False) { $!handled = 1 }
```

So that makes instances of a Failure object to be seen as not defined.
It will also cause the Failure to consider itself handled.
(If a Failure isn't handled it will throw a warning when it gets garbage collected.)

---

So what about `:exists` on `%h{'D'}`?
In Perl6 the “*normal*” operators are defined as subroutines with a special name.

```perl6
sub foo (%hash, $key){}

say &foo.signature.perl;
# :(%hash, $key)

say &postcircumfix:<{ }>.signature.perl;
# :($, $?, Mu $?, *%)
```

Note that the postcircumfix operator `{ }` is backed by several multi-subs, but we really only need to look at [one of them](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/e50f4f2e335a444d8ef2cb4d8c53bb4f63134fda/src/core/hash_slice.pm6#L24-L26).

```perl6
multi sub postcircumfix:<{ }>( \SELF, \key, Bool() :$exists!, *%other ) is raw {
    SLICE_ONE_HASH( SELF, key, 'exists', $exists, %other )
}
```

You can ignore most of that. The key thing to pay attention to is `:$exists!`.
By default named arguments are optional, and don't get a say in which multi gets selected.
In order for `:exists` to force this one to be selected it must be marked as required `!`.

Whenever you see `:exists` you can think of it as short for `:exists(True)` and `exists => True`.
(Also `:$exists` is short for `:exists($exists)` and `exists => $exists`.)

So both of these lines are functionally identical:

```perl6
my $exists = %h{'D'}:exists;

my $exists = postcircumfix:<{ }> %h, 'D', exists => True;
```

It tells the operator (subroutine) to use the `exists` variation.

Note that it also passes along the value of `$exists`, which means it can do inverted exists checks.

```perl6
say %h{'c'}:exists;  # True
say %h{'c'}:!exists; # False

say %h{'D'}:exists;  # False
say %h{'D'}:!exists; # True
```

`:!exists` is short for `:exists(False)` and `exists => False`.

---

So the reason there isn't `:defined` variation of postcircumfix `{ }` is that there doesn't need to be one. Just ask the resulting value if it was defined.

Answer (score 4):

The exact code you've got can be done much simpler in Perl 6, because of autovivification:

```
my %foo;
%foo<thekey>++;
say %foo.perl; # => {:thekey(1)}
```

Other than that, the difference between `defined %foo<thekey>` and `%foo<thekey>:exists` is that you can put an undefined value into the hash at the given key and it'll answer `True` to `:exists` but `False` to `defined`.

Comment: undefined values are very dangerous in what I do, they're bugs waiting to blow up in my face, I do everything I can to avoid them.  I don't like how difficult it is to get warnings about undefined values in Perl6. Perl6 should have `use warnings 'FATAL' => 'all'` like in Perl5, but it doesn't.  Perl6's `use fatal` is insufficient in my experience.

Comment: @con That doesn't matter in this case. In Perl5 with `use warnings 'FATAL' => 'all'` it wouldn't generate an error for this either. `perl -Mwarnings=FATAL,all -E 'my %h; say $h{key}++'`